# What fpu_xrstor_checking does? extra commentary?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, x86-64

I am doing my own version of do_fork() (for many purposes). So, basically, I am copying the process from one place to another, possibly to another machine. Copying the code and pasting it here would be tough. But this explanation should good enough, I believe.

My code works most of the times, but in other times the function `fpu_xrstor_checking()` returns an error (value = -1). Can anyone please explain what this function is supposed to do and extra commentary?

Here is the function pasted here for convenience:

```
 45 static inline int fpu_xrstor_checking(struct fpu *fpu)
 46 {
 47         struct xsave_struct *fx = &fpu->state->xsave;
 48         int err;
 49 
 50         asm volatile("1: .byte " REX_PREFIX "0x0f,0xae,0x2f\n\t"
 51                      "2:\n"
 52                      ".section .fixup,\"ax\"\n"
 53                      "3:  movl $-1,%[err]\n"
 54                      "    jmp  2b\n"
 55                      ".previous\n"
 56                      _ASM_EXTABLE(1b, 3b)
 57                      : [err] "=r" (err)
 58                      : "D" (fx), "m" (*fx), "a" (-1), "d" (-1), "" (0)
 59                      : "memory");
 60 
 61         return err;
 62 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inline assembly make use of a feature of Linux kernel that allow developer to "catch" CPU exceptions. The instruction at label `1` is a `XRSTOR` (more on this later).
The code at label `3` is emitted in the `.fixup` section that contain code used to handle exceptions.
The `_ASM_EXTABLE` tell the assembler to generate a table structure to inform the kernel that the instruction at `1` may generate an exception and that its handler is at `3`.

The handler just set the `err` to -1.
The `XRSTOR` instruction (coded with opcodes maybe because the assembler does not support it yet?) restore the following part of the CPU architectural state: **x87 (FPU)**, **SSE**, **AVX**.
The instruction take EDX:EAX as a mask (called the instruction mask) and it is quite elaborate, it can generate a #GP for a lot of reasons, listing them here would be pointless (one cause being its operand not aligned on 64 **byte** boundary).
When this instruction faults the function return -1.

I suggest the reading of the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 1](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.html) *Section 13* for a full description of the topic (general understanding of Section 8-12 are required).  You can also read the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 2b](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2b-manual.html) for the instruction `XRSTOR` reference with a full list of reasons for the exceptions that can be generated.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Now, my question is...in a regular process fork (i.e. plain vanilla Linux) where in the code these registers are copied from parent to child?

Comment: @hebbo, I'm not an expert of Linux kernel so don't heavy rely on this comment :) These register may be copied from parent to child in [fpu_copy](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/fpu-internal.h#L596) called by [arch_dup_task_struct](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/process.c#L86) called by [dup_task_struct](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c#L328) called by [copy_process](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c#L1239) called by fork.

Comment: This [book preview](https://books.google.it/books?id=h0lltXyJ8aIC&pg=PT127&lpg=PT127&dq=linux+fork+fpu+registers&source=bl&ots=gO2qF_bfMT&sig=XQlwINsFCqS3xaE61rt5-2prDaA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2ZCJVdD0MoORsgH_rZSYBQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAg) is interesting as FPU/MMX/SSE/AVX state are copied only when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just read it and spent more time on the assembly and understanding inlined assembly in general and I think I got. I also think I know how to fix my code ;)